# Dynamic hide/show divs after click on respective buttons with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide

I have some `divs` that, when clicked, have to show other specific `divs` (with relative content) and hide all the others.
I think it's a very simple request, but it gave me headache.

this is my code, hope that someone can help me:

```js
$('.finiture-wrapper').on('click', function() {
        var idBtn = $(this).data('id');
        //console.log(idBtn);     
        if(idBtn == $('allestimento-img-wrapper').data('id')){
        $('allestimento-img-wrapper').css('display', 'flex')
        }
        else{
        $('allestimento-img-wrapper').css('display', 'none')
        }
        
    })
```

```css
.allestimento-img-wrapper{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="finiture-wrapper" data-id="silver-bagno-1">bagno 1</button>
<button class="finiture-wrapper" data-id="silver-bagno-2">bagno 2</button>
<button class="finiture-wrapper" data-id="silver-bagno-3">bagno 3</button>

<div class="allestimento-img-wrapper"  data-id="silver-bagno-1">content 1</div>
<div class="allestimento-img-wrapper" data-id="silver-bagno-2">content 2</div>
<div class="allestimento-img-wrapper" data-id="silver-bagno-3">content 3</div>
```

I've used `data-id` to connect the two `divs` but i can't properly show it.
Plus, I'm trying to use if/else statement but maybe there is a smarter way.

Thank you.
P.s. I'm super new to jquery, and this question may seems stupid.

Comment: check jQuery toggle http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: check my answer it might help you bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should first hilde all other div and then from btn id open the selected div,
your html should be like this

```
<button class="finiture-wrapper" data-id="silver-bagno-1">bagno 1</button>
<button class="finiture-wrapper" data-id="silver-bagno-2">bagno 2</button>
<button class="finiture-wrapper" data-id="silver-bagno-3">bagno 3</button>

<div class="allestimento-img-wrapper"  id="div_silver-bagno-1">content 
1</div>
<div class="allestimento-img-wrapper" id="div_silver-bagno-2">content 
2</div>
<div class="allestimento-img-wrapper" id="div_silver-bagno-3">content 
3</div>
```

your javascript shold be like this

```
$('.finiture-wrapper').on('click', function() {
    //first hide all other div
    $(".allestimento-img-wrapper").hide();
    var idBtn = $(this).data('id');
    //now open the selected div
    $("#div_"+idBtn).css('display', 'flex');
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  it worked perfecty! I've just another question. If I want that one particular `div` is visible on the pageload? how do i do that? Let's say, I want that `id="div_silver-bagno-1"` is visible on start. How could I make it visible and then hide it when I click on others?

Comment: @s.zane you can do this with css using first-child property ,first child of a class 'allestimento-img-wrapper' by default  visible and rest are hidden

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.finiture-wrapper').on('click', function() {
        var idBtn = $(this).data('id');

        if(idBtn === $('allestimento-img-wrapper').data('id')){
         $('.allestimento-img-wrapper').css('display', 'flex')
         $('.allestimento-img-wrapper').data('id');
        }
        if(if(idBtn !== $('allestimento-img-wrapper').data('id')){
         $('.allestimento-img-wrapper').css('display', 'none');
        }
       })
```

I think U forgot the (.) point in jQuery.
Hope It will solve the problem.

Comment: Is this tested?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply show and hide div by jquery show and hide function.

Check the below code it might help you.

```
$('allestimento-img-wrapper').show(); //To show the div.
$('allestimento-img-wrapper').hide(); //To hide the div.
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `data-id` selector to get the corresponding data-id of the div Hope this solves your problem, thanks

```js
$('.finiture-wrapper').on('click', function() {
$(this).siblings('div[data-id="'+$(this).attr('data-id')+'"]').removeClass('allestimento-img-wrapper').siblings('div').addClass('allestimento-img-wrapper') 
})
```

```css
.allestimento-img-wrapper{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="finiture-wrapper" data-id="silver-bagno-1">bagno 1</button>
<button class="finiture-wrapper" data-id="silver-bagno-2">bagno 2</button>
<button class="finiture-wrapper" data-id="silver-bagno-3">bagno 3</button>
<button class="finiture-wrapper" data-id="silver-bagno-4">bagno 4</button>
 
<div class="allestimento-img-wrapper"  data-id="silver-bagno-1">content 1</div>
<div class="allestimento-img-wrapper" data-id="silver-bagno-2">content 2</div>
<div class="allestimento-img-wrapper" data-id="silver-bagno-3">content 3</div>
<div class="allestimento-img-wrapper" data-id="silver-bagno-4">content 4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the code please check.

```
<button class="finiture-wrapper" data-id="silver-bagno-1">bagno 1</button>
<button class="finiture-wrapper" data-id="silver-bagno-2">bagno 2</button>
<button class="finiture-wrapper" data-id="silver-bagno-3">bagno 3</button>

<div class="silver-bagno-1 commonclass"  >content 1</div>
<div class="silver-bagno-1 commonclass" >content 2</div>
<div class="silver-bagno-1 commonclass" >content 3</div>

<script>
$(".finiture-wrapper").click(function(){
var getbtnid=$(this).data("id");
$(".commonclass").hide();
$("."+getbtnid).show();
};

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Change your `jQuery` without `If else` Condition

```js
$('.finiture-wrapper').on('click', function() {
    var idBtn = $(this).data('id');
    $('.allestimento-img-wrapper').css('display', 'none')
    $('div[data-id*=' +  idBtn + ']').css('display', 'flex');        
});
```

```css
.allestimento-img-wrapper{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="finiture-wrapper" data-id="silver-bagno-1">bagno 1</button>
<button class="finiture-wrapper" data-id="silver-bagno-2">bagno 2</button>
<button class="finiture-wrapper" data-id="silver-bagno-3">bagno 3</button>

<div class="allestimento-img-wrapper"  data-id="silver-bagno-1">content 1</div>
<div class="allestimento-img-wrapper" data-id="silver-bagno-2">content 2</div>
<div class="allestimento-img-wrapper" data-id="silver-bagno-3">content 3</div>
```